# How to call watch() using pubsub service object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google-api-client gem to integrate google services into my Rails application. with the scope of PubSub I am able to create topic and subscriptions in my a/c but I am facing issues while calling watch() method. Can anyone give me the flow to call watch method through service object like  below
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch

Following is my script to get service object

```
pubsub_service = Google::Apis::PubsubV1::PubsubService.new
pubsub_service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
pubsub_service.authorization = authorize
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give publish permission on your topic to a service account *gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com*. For how to do this, please see:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic